# Magento WSDL URL being redirected to admin page

Tags: .net, api, magento, wsdl

I have a .NET app and I'm trying to add a web reference to a Magento web service by specifying production.mydomain.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl and in my app.config file I can see the reference written as manager.mydomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/.

When I browse manager.mydomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/ I am being prompted for a login because it takes me to the Magento admin page.

However, when I add a web reference to the Magento web service by specifying dev.mydomain.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl  the app.config file reference is written as dev.mydomain/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/. This works because my .NET app can see the methods defined by the WSDL.

In the first instance, I get an error like-- Redirection limit reached, aborting#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->_*doRequest('*_call('login', Array).

For the dev environment the base_url is the same as the URL I use to access the web server which is dev.mydomain.com/

For the production environment the base_url is defined as manager.mydomain.com/

Has anybody encountered this? What do I need to change? Is this a Magento configuration issue or an Apache configuration issue?

Seems to me that Magento is rewriting the URL for production.mydomain.com to manager.mydomain.com